# Resistance measurement and standard uncertainty

Tags: measurement, accuracy

In a text there is a section regarding a basic example for uncertainty calculation of a resistor. Here is the related part:

[image]

Above the text uses the the accuracy of the current source and the voltmeter.

But if we were able to see the voltmeter's data sample measurements as below:

[image]

Is the text talking about B type systematic uncertainties given in device datasheets? And if we have the voltage data samples should we also add the standard uncertainty as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, text is talking about B type.

Should you include A type as well? It depends on your requirements. If you want, you can limit yourself on type A (measurement dispersion, essentially) or type B (instrumentation uncertainty). But normally what metrologists provide with *measurements* is combined uncertainty. For combined you usually calculate your values from measurements and then assign *weighting coefficient* (derivative of function) to it.

More information: [about types A and B](https://www.isobudgets.com/type-a-and-type-b-uncertainty/) and [Combined uncertainty](https://www.nde-ed.org/GeneralResources/Uncertainty/Combined.htm) and the [GUM bible itself](https://www.bipm.org/utils/common/documents/jcgm/JCGM_100_2008_E.pdf)